# Spatial Data with SQL Server 2008 & Virtual Earth

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, geospatial

I am loading the spatial data from Geoconcept Navteq UK Map to SQL Server 2008.In geoconcept the geometry field is, sepparated values of Longitude and Latitude.

I have written a one webhandler to connect to database and retrieve data in the form of GML.From that GML ,i am creating one Georss feed.I am displaying on top of virtual earth.

Here comes the problem ,Georss feed contains point in the form of Latitude and Longitude.but geoconcept is returning me Longitude and latitude.

Due to this i am getting the points not in correct way?

can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 1):

Try reversing the points in the retreiving query. Something like this:

```
select 
geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + cast(geomColumn.STY as varchar(50)) + ' ' + cast(geomColumn.STX as varchar(50))+ ')',0) as NewGeomColumn
from tablename
```